# UnwindToList from IOS Tutorial does not activate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have followed the "Start Developing iOS Apps Today" tutorial.

The application has generally built as I expected. However the following block has not worked.

o link buttons to the unwindToList: action

1) In the project navigator, select Main.storyboard.

2) On the canvas, Control-drag from the Cancel button to the Exit item in the add-to-do-item scene dock.If you don’t see the Exit item in the scene dock but instead see the description of the scene, click the Zoom In image: ../Art/zoom_in_2x.png button on the canvas until you see it.A menu appears in the location where the drag ended.

3) Choose unwindToList: from the shortcut menu.This is the action you just added to the XYZToDoListViewController.m file. This means that when the Cancel button is tapped, the segue will unwind and this method will be called.

4) On the canvas, Control-drag from the Done button to the Exit item in theXYZAddToDoItemViewController scene dock.

5)Choose unwindToList: from the shortcut menu.

All the other directions on the tutorials have worked. The build compiles without error. When the app runs in the Simulator the  user clicks Done or Cancel, but the focus does not move back to the ToDoList scene. It just stays on the Add Item screen.

Any ideas on what is happening.
iOS 7.1

Some further detail

**This is the ToDoController.m with the unwindToList**

```
 -(IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
ianNo00004AddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
ianNo00004ToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;

if (item != nil) {
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

}

**This is the ToDoListController.h**

@interface ianNo00004ToDoListViewController : UITableViewController

-(IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@end
```

**The AddToItemViewController.m code**
    #import "ianNo00004AddToDoItemViewController.h"

```
@interface ianNo00004AddToDoItemViewController ()


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;


@end

@implementation ianNo00004AddToDoItemViewController

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if (sender != self.doneButton) return;
if (self.textField.text.length > 0)
{
    self.toDoItem = [[ianNo00004ToDoItem alloc] init];
    self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
    self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
}

}
```

Comment: It's hard to diagnose these kinds of problems that involve hookups in IB rather than code without seeing the project. I'm sure somebody can help if you can upload the project somewhere.

Comment: This is the code in the ToDoListController.m

Comment: Added the relevant code.

Comment: The first stage of linking the buttons to the Segue was to link to an empty function. This did not work. I think the error is with _-(IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{}_

Comment: I don't know what error you think would be in that method. As long as you have that method (with the correct signature, which you do), then the unwind should work. There doesn't need to be any code in that method for the segue to work properly. As I said, your problem is probably something wrongly setup in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add method **unwindToList** in **XYZToDoListTableViewController.h**

### (not the ItemViewController, but the TableViewController)

```
@interface XYZToDoListTableViewController : UITableViewController
    -(IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end
```

Then add the following code in XYZToDoListTableViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

}
```

The tutorial which you used may be the old version, there might be some errors.
Follow the latest version here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW7

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same example and had mine working. Have a look at the connections inspector on your Add To-Do Item on the storyboard for both the cancel and done buttons and see if they have actions for the triggered Segues. 
I removed the action from both buttons on my project and the Add To-Do Item wouldn't close, so I think you are missing those actions.